# Including container views within a UIScrollView using Storyboards

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, storyboard

I am programming the layout of a UIScrollView with several different subview components.

I have laid these out by inserting Container objects into the UIScrollView in a specific layout.

Previously on views which do not include a UIScrollView, I have had success instantiating the view controller that should appear within the container via this method below.

```
fpqtvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"fptable"];
fpqtvc.frontPageQuery = [self selectFrontPageQuery:0];

[self addChildViewController:fpqtvc];


[self.stage addSubview:fpqtvc.view];
fpqtvc.view.frame = self.stage.bounds;
```

stage is set to an outlet of the containerview.

When I try to replicate this method using a UIScrollView, I run into some issues.
1) There is no addchildviewcontroller method for a UIScrollView. I'm not sure this will be a problem. 
2) If I programatically add the view as a subview, it does not respect the layout I have used in my storyboard.

Is there a way to load my UIScrollview and its container views where the UIScrollview will reflect how they are laid out within?

Comment: I have researched it some more and even loading all of the subviews into a separate view controller and loading that view controller as the only subview of the UIScrollview, it was still not showing all of them and was not resizing correctly.

Comment: The only way to go appears to be just programatically setting all of the layouts of each subview like in the raywenderlich tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Since a scroll view is a UIView, you can only use addSubview: to add children to it.  You can do that in code or you can do it by dragging objects in Interface Builder.  The scrollview won't change the layout of its children unless you have told it to.  Are you using auto-layout?  Auto-resizing masks?  Does the scrollview have autoResizesSubviews = YES?

Comment: I am using auto layout.  I am not sure about auto resizing masks.  The scrollview does have autosize subviews flagged to yes.  Thanks for helping!

Comment: This tutorial kind of addresses what I am looking to do, but in their solution you are manually entering the layout of things in the container that's inside the scrollview.  http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content